# There is an Out of the Box SP ListBox that allows the user to select options and display them on another ListBox?

Tags: 2010, user-controls, out-of-the-box

Basically those are two DropDownLists, but I'm wondering if there's an OOB webpart.

Example:

[image]

Update:
I have found a lot of insight in this [page](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=es&u=http://www.weboomania.com/2009/12/14/usando-el-groupeditempicker-de-sharepoint/), that is a translation of this [blog post](http://www.weboomania.com/2009/12/14/usando-el-groupeditempicker-de-sharepoint/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a control called the [GroupedItemPicker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.groupeditempicker.aspx) that is used on the "Add Columns from Site Columns" page (and I'm sure other places)

Answer (score 0):

If the column is configured for choice : multiple values allowed

> List settings --> choice column --> allow multiple values